# My delegate isn't passing my JSON value to the UILabel in the View Controller

Tags: ios, json, swift, delegates

Ive made a delegate that passes the JSON value to my view controller so that I can change two UILabels, but when I run my app the labels don't change. I've been stuck on this for a long time and everything I do just leads to the app staying the same when I change the currency with my picker view. Help would be appreciated. Thank you.

**Delegate**

```
protocol coinManagerDelegate {
    func didUpdateCoin(price: String, currency: String)
    func didFailWithError(error: Error)
}
```

**Function**

```
   func performRequest(with Currency: String) {
        let stringURL = baseURL + Currency + apiKey
        AF.request(stringURL).responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let value):
                let json = JSON(value)
                if let rate = json["rate"].double {
                    print(rate)
                    let totalRate = String(format: "%.2f", rate)
                    print(totalRate)
                    self.delegate?.didUpdateCoin(price: totalRate, currency: Currency)
                }
                
                
                
            case .failure(let error):
                self.delegate?.didFailWithError(error: error)
            }
        }
    }
```

**View Controller**

```
extension ViewController: coinManagerDelegate {
    func didFailWithError(error: Error) {
        print(error)
    }
    
    func didUpdateCoin(price: String, currency: String) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.bitcoinLabel.text = price
            self.currencyLabel.text = currency
        }
    }
}
```

**Calling performRequest**

```
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        let selectedCurrency = coinManager.currencyArray[row]
        coinManager.performRequest(with: selectedCurrency)
    }
```

Comment: Show how you're calling `performRequest` and where you're setting the delegate.

Comment: Show where you set the delegate

Comment: @Frankenstein I updated it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the `delegate` in the `ViewController`.

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    let selectedCurrency = coinManager.currencyArray[row]
    coinManager.delegate = self
    coinManager.performRequest(with: selectedCurrency)
}
```